# User Log in page

Tags: php, sql, authentication, user-profile

I have posted similar code here recently but still couldn't get it working properly.
I have attempted to rewrite the script but it's still not working - all i am getting is a grey box in the top right corner of the screen.
The idea is that someone logs in and this is used to display their profile information to the screen. I am trying to get the users data from the row that matches their email address which I am using as the username.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is the last bit I need to get working to complete the technical bits of my site.

Thanks.

```
<?php # DISPLAY USER DATA/PROFILE
# Access session.
session_start() ;

# Redirect if not logged in.
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] ) ) { require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ; load() ; }

# Set page title and display header section.
$page_title = 'Forum' ;


# Open database connection.
require ( 'connect_db.php' ) ;

# Display body section, retrieving from 'forum' database table.
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = {$_SESSION['email']}" ;
$r = mysqli_query( $dbc, $q ) ;

   echo '<tr><td>' . $r['first_name'] .' '. $r['last_name'] . '<br>'. $r['email'].'</td>     <td>' . '</td><td>' . '</td> </tr>';

#  Close database connection.
mysqli_close( $dbc ) ;

?>
```

****NOW****

```
<?php # DISPLAY COMPLETE FORUM PAGE.

# Access session.
session_start() ;

# Redirect if not logged in.
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] ) ) { require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ; load() ; }

# Set page title and display header section.
$page_title = 'Forum' ;


# Open database connection.
require ( 'connect_db.php' ) ;

# Display body section, retrieving from 'forum' database table.
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = {$_SESSION['email']}" ;
$r = mysqli_query( $dbc, $q ) ;
$results = $r -> fetchAssoc() ;

   echo '<tr><td>' . $results['first_name'] .' '. $r['last_name'] . '<br>'. $r['email'].'</td> <td>' . '</td><td>' . '</td> </tr>';

# Close database connection.
mysqli_close( $dbc ) ;

?>
```

The error now shows " Call to a member function fetchAssoc() on a non-object" - line 19 which is the new line that I have added
     $results = $r -> fetchAssoc() ;

Comment: I was using if/else statements but this was overcomplicating things for me.

Comment: You're trying to use the result set directly, but you need to fetch data from it first.

Comment: That error normally means that your query has failed. In this case, I expect it's because you need to wrap the value in quotes `WHERE email ='{$_SESSION['email']}'`. But you should probably look at using a prepared statement instead - you're already using mysqli, and it's much more secure.

Answer (score 0):

After your $r = mysqli_query(), add $results = $r->fetchAssoc();

Then you can access the fields via $results['first_name'], for example.

Side note: you should consider testing if rows exist, error catching, etc. May even wish to consider switching to using PDO instead.

Comment: Is this better??    'code' # Open database connection.
require ( 'connect_db.php' ) ;

# Display body section, retrieving from 'forum' database table.
$q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = {$_SESSION['email']}" ;
$r = mysqli_query( $dbc, $q ) ;
$results = $r -> fetchAssoc() ;

   echo '<tr><td>' . $results['first_name'] .' '. $r['last_name'] . '<br>'. $r['email'].'</td> <td>' . '</td><td>' . '</td> </tr>';

Comment: I will pdate the code above so it is easier to read!  Thanks.